# Web API how to secure token when using IFrame on clientside

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, access-token, asp.net-web-api2

I have a **ASP.NET Web API** server application and `Javascript` frontend.

The way Im implementing authentication is by using a Token that is sent and received in the `HTTP Response Headers`.

When the users log into the application, my server will send back to the client a JSON object with a session Token. The javascript client then stores that in a browser cookie.

> Every call that the javascript client makes to the server, the token is sent in to a custom header so the server can decrypt that and validate it in the database so it know if its a valid session.

Everything works great here, If I need to secure that part then adding a SSL will help.

Now, there are calls in the app that I need to use an `IFrame` so I set the `src` property to the web api method I need to call.

> > **It's not possible to add a custom HTTP Header when using IFrame, just a simple URL into src property**

Of course using this there is no way to send a `custom header` so what I did was to append a parameter into the `scr url` like this:

```
<iframe scr="/api/report/GenerateReport?sessionUid=" + getCookie('sessionuid') ></iframe>
```

This is my web api method that receives the `sessionUid` as a parameter.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GenerateReport(string sessionUid) {

    // validates session
    bool validSession = common.ValidateSession(sessionUid);

    if (validSession) {

        // do some stuff here
    }

}
```

My question is... how can I secure my token, because if someone steals the sessionuid he then can call all the `HttpGet` methods that receives `sessionUid` as a parameter?

Any clue?

Comment: Instead of using a *custom* header, why not use the `Authorization` header? Something like this: `Authorization: Token your_sessionUid_here`. The `Token` scheme is made up, but you don't care. All you need is your session uid from the header. Then you don't have to worry about exposing your token in the URI.

Comment: Using IFrame that's not possible. I was trying to read about it and there is no way to send an http header in the IFrame src propoerty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website is not using SSL, then you cannot 100% secure the communication between your website and user's browser.

Attackers usually hijack you whole HTTP package, including HTTP headers, put session in HTTP header is not enough for security.

Comment: And what bout the url with sessionuid parameter? because the SSL will no affect that part.

Comment: I think putting information into URL instead of HTTP header does not affect the security, the only different situation is that another person behind you sees the URL in your browser and memorize that information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific question is to encrypt the querystring parameters.